# Inconsistent results for LASSO (glmnet package)

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, lasso, glmnet, lars

I am getting inconsistent results (coefficients and the mean cross-validated error) with the glmnet package in R. The data set has 33 variables and 250 observations. This is the sample output for the R2:

```
> cvfit2 <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(datam, fundm,alpha=1,nfolds=10)
> max(1-cvfit2$cvm/var(fundm))
[1] 0.5264011
> cvfit2 <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(datam, fundm,alpha=1,nfolds=10)
> max(1-cvfit2$cvm/var(fundm))
[1] 0.5342929
> cvfit2 <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(datam, fundm,alpha=1,nfolds=10)
> max(1-cvfit2$cvm/var(fundm))
[1] 0.5025206
```

I tried setting set.seed(123), but it doesn't make any difference - the outputs still show 2-3% deviations.

My questions:

1. Is such inconsistency normal or there are some settings I am missing?
2. Could it be related to correlated variables? I have found some references that "*LASSO has selection inconsistency if there is a group of highly correlated true variables*" - see [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4026268/).

Comment: How correlated are your variables? A summary metric would be `kappa(X)` where `X` is your design matrix. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about this too much.

Comment: Kappa is huge: 1.009311e+17

Comment: Okay that's probably why. When kappa is greater than, say, 1e15, it means that it's much harder to find the exact minimum of the lasso objective function. You can think of this statistically as having a high standard error around your minimum.

Comment: Consider performing elastic net regression instead of LASSO.

Comment: OK, then it would make sense to run PCA first. Actually, I tried setting alpha=0 as the ridge penalty, but it does't make any difference.

Comment: You should higher the penalty, not set it to zero. Typically, the higher kappa is, the higher the optimal ridge penalty tends to be.

Comment: Your fit is being determined by cross validation, which involves selecting random subsets of the data. *Ergo*, you must *expect* the results to vary.  The easiest check of consistency, then, is to set the random number seed to a fixed value just before running the code.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I already tried set.seed(123) before calling glmnet (see my post), but it doesn't make any difference - still slightly different results.